# After using Apply Symbology From Layer in ArcGIS Pro layer becomes invisible

Tags: layers, symbology, arcgis-pro

The layer still exists, i can open the attribute table, zoom to the layer etc.

And if i change the Symbology manually, it reappears.

Anyone knows why and how to fix it?

[image: The symbology i'm trying to apply]

Comment: What symbology does the layer you are applying from have?  You could show a picture of the symbol patch and the Symbology pane for that symbol.

Comment: i added a capture at the main question

Comment: Does the layer that you are applying this symbology to have the "Multi Dg" field, with the same name underneath (because that looks like an alias)?

Comment: Yes, thats probably it.. It's a JOIN field, so it will be different in every layer..

Is there a way to apply the symbology by alias?

Comment: You may need to Alter Field first.